# Como criar evento entre transição de sessões?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, rolamento

Possuo um **elemento** `<a>` em meu `.html`, onde eu necessito que quando houvesse o **evento** de `onclick` no mesmo, ocorreria o **efeito de transição de sessão**, ou seja:

> Com o **evento** `onclick` no **elemento** `<a>` **automaticamente ele iria transitar entre cada sessão do meu** `<body>`.

**O que eu consegui desenvolver foi o seguinte:**

> Conforme a **cada clique** no **elemento**  o mesmo desce a cada sessão.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="scroll">
    <a href="#" class="defaut-btn-gradient -button scroll"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i> Scroll Down</a>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section1"></div>
<div class="section" id="section2"></div>
        <script>
var secs = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
var currentSection = 0;
document.querySelector('#scroll').addEventListener('click', move);

function move(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('scroll') && currentSection < secs.length) {
    window.scroll({
      top: secs[++currentSection].offsetTop,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
    //    secs[++currentSection].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  } else if (currentSection > 0) {
    window.scroll({
      top: secs[--currentSection].offsetTop,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });

  }
}
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sugiro que leia as diretrizes da comunidade para criar uma [boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ela esta um pouco confusa e é necessário você postar todo o código referente ao assunto da pergunta, para melhorar a análise dos usuários.

Answer (score 1):

Você teria que fazer mais ou menos isso:

```js
var secs = document.querySelectorAll('section');
var currentSection = 0;
document.querySelector('#arrow').addEventListener('click', move);

function move(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('next') && currentSection < secs.length) {
    window.scroll({
      top: secs[++currentSection].offsetTop,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
    //    secs[++currentSection].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  } else if (currentSection > 0) {
    window.scroll({
      top: secs[--currentSection].offsetTop,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });

  }
}
```

```css
section {
  min-height: 800px;
}

#arrow {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#arrow a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="arrow">
  <a class="previous">anterior</a>
  <a class="next">proximo</a>
</div>
<section style="background-color:green">
  <h1>

    Lorem ipsum<br> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, earum unde, deleniti id tempore atque in nemo reprehenderit ad odit, nisi blanditiis<br> odio pariatur<br> non tempora ducimus tenetur nobis quibusdam?</h1>
</section>
<section style="background-color:blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br> amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus cum officia culpa quia id, dicta voluptatem aspernatur reprehenderit repellendus minima, sapiente mollitia dolore magnam delectus, ad eius ut iusto eos?</section>
<section style="background-color:red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br> amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur magnam illo possimus rerum ratione. Quos harum dicta nihil illum atque, consequatur<br> cupiditate sint fugiat dolores consectetur quasi deserunt repellendus enim.</section>
```

Utilizando do botão "Proximo" como o seu botão.

Comment: Opa cara obrigado pela resposta eu sou muito iniciante em js meu site nao usa sections e sim div com class section e um id com o numero da section o link está na descrição da pergunta olhando como está estruturado como ficaria seu código em uma versão adaptada para meu código poderia quebrar essa ?

Comment: eu editei a pergunta lá se conseguir me ajudar porque no seu código você adapta a <section> no meu caso eu uso div

Comment: Aqui: `var secs = document.querySelectorAll('section');` você vai alterar para `var secs = document.querySelectorAll('.section');`

Answer (score 0):

Existem diversas formas de fazer este tipo de "animação", as quais são:

- Utilizar o **Jquery** (Para os dias de hoje o Jquery esta totalmente antiquado o seu uso)
- Utilizar **Function** (criar uma simples função Javascript + ECMASCRIPT e manipular os `id` das `<section>`)

Eu irei te passar o funcionamento de como **eu utilizaria** e o qual **eu acho correto para os dias de hoje**, onde é utilizando a `Function`, mas para isto, antes eu preciso te explicar sobre o evento `Window.location`.

**Window.location**

> A propriedade `Window.location` é somente para leitura e retorna um objeto `Location` com informações sobre o local atual do documento. Embora `Window.location` seja um objeto somente de leitura do `Location` , você também pode atribuir um `DOMString` a ele. Isso significa que você pode trabalhar com o `location` como se fosse uma string na maioria dos casos: `location = 'http://www.example.com'` é sinônimo de `location.href = 'http://www.example.com'`.
>
> [FONTE: MOZZILA DEVELOPER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Neste caso eu utilizarei a propriedade `.href` do `Window.location`, onde:

**Location.href**

> É um `DOMString` contendo o URL inteiro. Se alterado, o documento associado navega para a nova página. Pode ser definido a partir de uma origem diferente do documento associado.
>
> [FONTE: MOZZILA DEVELOPER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>ÂNCORAS DE SESSÕES</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="section-one" style="background-color: red; padding: 300px">
        <h1>SEÇÃO (1)</h1>
    </section>

    <section id="section-two" style="background-color: blue; padding: 300px">
        <h1>SEÇÃO (2)</h1>
    </section>

    <section id="section-three" style="background-color: green; padding: 300px">
        <h1>SEÇÃO (3)</h1>
    </section>

    <section id="section-for" style="background-color: yellow; padding: 300px">
        <h1>SEÇÃO (4)</h1>
    </section>

    <script>
        function alterarSessao(_sectionID, _sectionGoToID) {
            document.getElementById(`${_sectionID}`).addEventListener('click', (_event) => window.location.href = `#${_sectionGoToID}`);
        }

        alterarSessao('section-one',   'section-two');
        alterarSessao('section-two',   'section-three');
        alterarSessao('section-three', 'section-for');
        alterarSessao('section-for',   'section-one');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTA:**

> Para animar o scroll até o determinado section você tem duas opções, as quais são:
>
> - Desenvolver um Algoritmo
> - Utilizar Bibliotecas já prontas como por exemplo o [ScrollMagic](https://scrollmagic.io/)